# How to COUNTIFS across columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, boolean

I want to sum the number of each value in across columns. This is the equivalent to COUNTIFs in Excel.  However, I want the values populated in the columns, and not in a separate groupby statement.

So, if Row 1 had 5 columns with the following values: 1, 1, 3, 1, 5

then Rating_1 = 3, Rating_2=0, Rating_3=1, Rating_4= 0, and Rating_5 = 1
or (3, 0, 1, 0, 1)

I'm using the following code, and am unable to get the boolean values to add within the loop (all of my research shows they should add up fine!).

Right now, I get the following (binary) output: 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 (when it should be 3, 0, 1, 0, 1)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,5,size=(5, 5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))

for val in range(1,6):
    df['Rating_' + str(val)] = 0

for val in range(1,6):
    for row in range(0, df.shape[0]):
        df['Rating_' + str(val)][row] = ((df['A'][row] == val) +  (df['B'][row] == val) +  (df['C'][row] == val) +  (df['D'][row] == val) +  (df['E'][row] == val)).sum()
```

Also happy to make this code cleaner and more efficient, but most concerned with getting it to work!  Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: you don't need any loops for this, but your existing data structure and desired output isn't clear

Comment: Can you add an actual readable example dataset and what your expected output is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `groupby` to create a temp dataframe, which you can process and finally merge with `df`.

```
np.random.seed(1) # always add a sample with random state for reproducibility
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,5,size=(5, 5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))


df2 = df.stack().droplevel(-1).reset_index()
df2 = (
    df2.groupby(df2.columns.to_list())
    .size().unstack()
    .fillna(0).astype(int)
)
df = pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1)
```

Output

```
   A  B  C  D  E  0  1  2  3  4
0  3  4  0  1  3  1  1  0  2  1
1  0  0  1  4  4  2  1  0  0  2
2  1  2  4  2  4  0  1  2  0  2
3  3  4  2  4  2  0  0  2  1  2
4  4  1  1  0  1  1  3  0  0  1
```

I understand that this looks very similar to how you would add formulas in excel, but consider keeping the data and results as separate dataframes (i.e. skip the `pd.concat`) for better usability in further code. If you need to do something else with the original data you would have to drop the columns, it is just not common practice and anyone else using your code might not expect this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Clarifying the problem a bit.

```
df
    
   A  B  C  D  E  
0  4  3  4  2  0         
1  0  4  2  3  3          
2  3  4  1  2  1          
3  0  2  3  0  2          
4  2  4  1  3  2
```

Desired Result across the Rows:
Take Row 0.

1. Count occurences of 0s in the row. There is 1. Place this in column 'Ranking_0'
2. Count occurences of 1s in the row. There is 0. Place this in column 'Ranking_1'

And so on

Output Desired:

```
   A  B  C  D  E  Ranking_0  Ranking_1  Ranking_2  Ranking_3  Ranking_4
0  4  3  4  2  0          1          0          1          1          2
1  0  4  2  3  3          1          0          1          2          1
2  3  4  1  2  1          0          2          1          1          1
3  0  2  3  0  2          2          0          2          1          0
4  2  4  1  3  2          0          1          2          1          1
```

There are many ways to do this - so I'll use one that works for me with a little simplification.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,5,size=(5, 5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))

# The numbers you want to check for
nums = [0,1,2,3,4]
for num in nums: 
     df['Ranking_'+str(num)] = (df.iloc[:,0:5]).isin({num}).sum(1)
```

1. careful to just sum across your first 5 column else you will start adding in the Ranking_ columns! That is why I did `df.iloc[:,0:5)`
2. I used `.isin({})` just because it is clean.  There are other ways.
3. `.sum(1)` sums along the horizontal row (axis=1)